# Convert time stored in a variable as +%Y%m%d%H%M%S to second since epoch

Tags: bash, shell, time

There is a variable `var_date` which stores time in format `+%Y%m%d%H%M%S`, my requirement is to convert this into second since epoch.
One way to achieve this is to use date command with `-d` option like

```
date -d "$var_date" %s
```

but this does not work as `-d` option expect content of `var_date` to be in format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` and not `%Y%m%d%H%M%S`.
Is there any option using which i can convert time stored as `%Y%m%d%H%M%S` into second since epoch?

Comment: @tripleee
This is not the same question.
Problem here is input format is different +%Y%m%d%H%M%S which does not work with "-d" option in date command.

Comment: There are three duplicates which between them I believe cover every possible interpretation of your question. The first one does handle exactly what you seem to be describing.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56824/how-do-you-specify-a-format-for-the-input-to-date

Comment: @tripleee
Ya, first link matches.
Thanks.